# Motivation : min cut and max flow

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can someone explain the motivation behind the min cut and max flow problem?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jFoyLk2VjM  please see this one also

Answer (score 0):

it is  generally graph theory problem,with aim to find optimized  way in network for example,in this link there is detailed explanation
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos226/lectures/maxflow.4up.pdf